# convert from EST/EDT to GMT

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I convert a DateTime from EST/EDT to GMT but I don't know where the code will be ran (unknown local time zone) and also account for time savings...

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915.aspx), which allows you to pass the source time zone info as a parameter.  For example:

```
TimeZoneInfo est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime someDateTimeInUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(someDateTime, est);
```

I *think* this will automatically handle daylight-saving time, but you'll want to test it to be sure.

Comment: sorry i mean eastern time so it could be EST or EDT (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: it crashed when i used eastern time

Comment: Yup... if you look at the docs, and then look in your registry (where the FindSystemTimeZoneInfoById() does its lookup), you'll see that the "Eastern Standard Time" key has a "Dynamic DST" subkey... so *hopefully* the ConvertTimeToUtc() call will make use of it as needed.

Comment: @Comma... "it crashed when i used eastern time"... do you mean you passed "eastern time" to the FindSystemTimeZoneById() method?  You should pass "Eastern Standard Time", even though it will sometimes be a daylight-saving-time time.

Comment: Microsoft, Why is the timezone called Eastern Standard Time, when Eastern Standard Time is the non-DST version of the all-year name "Eastern Time"? Microsoft fucked up the naming here. so stupid and noone knows how it works because they used the wrong name.  blows the mind.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `TimeZoneInfo` class.