# How to convert a string containing a EDT related instant to a DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have a string in this format:

"Fri, 18 Mar 2011 18:53:15 EDT"

I want to convert this to datetime object, the problem is with EDT, at the end. If I use GMT DateTime.TryParse works fine, but if it is something else like EDT, it return false.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323145/convert-from-est-edt-to-gmt), or the [definitive time zone guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices).